# Cannot use older version of git-lfs on a repo created using latest version

Tags: git-lfs

I have a local repo with a bunch of git-lfs files tracked.  It was creted using git-lfs version 2.1.0.

If I try to do a checkout on that repo using git-lfs version 1.5.6, I get the error:

```
    Error: unknown command "post-checkout" for "git-lfs"
    Run 'git-lfs --help' for usage.
```

I get the same error after running `git-lfs install` in the repo.

Is git-lfs not backwards-compatible?

Comment: I got the same errror. Updating to the latest git-lfs version fixed the problem. It would appear it is not backwards compatible

Comment: how did you find which version of git-lfs was used by the repo? Just wanted to know, as it would help me out a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I guess the answer to your question is "no, git lfs is not backwards compatible".

You would need to update your git lfs version to a newer one for this to work properly.

You can see the latest release (and previous releases) here:

https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/releases