# Cannot checkout a file with Git LFS: `unknown command "post-checkout" for "git-lfs"`

Tags: git, git-lfs

When I do the following command while on a feature branch:

```
git checkout origin/master foo.js
```

I get the following error:

```
$ git checkout origin/master foo.js
Error: unknown command "post-checkout" for "git-lfs"
Run 'git-lfs --help' for usage.
```

Why is this happening and how do I fix this issue?

**Update**
From this question: [Cannot use older version of git-lfs on a repo created using latest version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43743717/cannot-use-older-version-of-git-lfs-on-a-repo-created-using-latest-version) it seems like it may be that I am using an older version of Git-LFS on the master branch compared to the feature branch (I may be wrong).

How can I check which version of GIT-LFS is being used for this feature branch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that v2 has a breaking change.

The solution is to simply update git-lfs!